# How to pass specific eosio-cpp/eosio-ld options via cmake

Tags: smart-contract, eosio.cdt, compilation, eosiocpp

I'm typically using CMake to compile my contracts, like described [here](https://developers.eos.io/manuals/eosio.cdt/latest/how-to-guides/compile/index).

How can I pass *specific eosio-cpp/eosio-ld options* (specifically *-stack-size*) described [here](https://developers.eos.io/manuals/eosio.cdt/v1.7/command-reference/eosio-cpp)?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`cmake` will compile source files into object files first and link them by linker, so you need to add `-stack-size` option to linker option. (When you run `eosio-cpp` in command-line, passing `-stack-size` to compile options is allowed, because `eosio-cpp` will pass linker options to `eosio-ld`)

```
add_contract(test test test.cpp)
target_link_options(test PUBLIC -stack-size=8192)
```

Comment: awesome, thank you @conrad!

Comment: sidenote for everyone reading this: target_link_options is only available in versions >= 3.13

Comment: @conrad, is there a way to pass options like -finline-functions and -finline-hint-functions via cmake?

Comment: @cmadh You can use `target_compile_options(test PUBLIC -finline-functions)` for them. My ID is conr"2"d, not conrad, haha.

Comment: oh, sry @conr2d :D. Thank you!